# How __hash__ is implemented in Python 3.2?

Tags: python, algorithm, hash

I want to make custom object hash-able (via pickling).  I could find `__hash__` algorithm for Python 2.x (see code below), but it obviously **differs** from hash for Python 3.2 (I wonder why?). Does anybody know how `__hash__` implemented in Python 3.2?

```
#Version: Python 3.2

def c_mul(a, b):
    #C type multiplication
    return eval(hex((int(a) * b) & 0xFFFFFFFF)[:-1])

class hs:
    #Python 2.x algorithm for hash from http://effbot.org/zone/python-hash.htm
    def __hash__(self):
        if not self:
            return 0 # empty
        value = ord(self[0]) << 7
        for char in self:
            value = c_mul(1000003, value) ^ ord(char)
        value = value ^ len(self)
        if value == -1:
            value = -2
        return value


def main():
    s = ["PROBLEM", "PROBLEN", "PROBLEO", "PROBLEP"]#, "PROBLEQ", "PROBLER", "PROBLES"]
    print("Python 3.2 hash() bild-in")
    for c in s[:]: print("hash('", c, "')=", hex(hash(c)),  end="\n")
    print("\n")
    print("Python 2.x type hash: __hash__()")
    for c in s[:]: print("hs.__hash__('", c, "')=", hex(hs.__hash__(c)),  end="\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

```
OUTPUT:
Python 3.2 hash() bild-in
hash(' PROBLEM ')= 0x7a8e675a
hash(' PROBLEN ')= 0x7a8e6759
hash(' PROBLEO ')= 0x7a8e6758
hash(' PROBLEP ')= 0x7a8e6747


Python 2.x type hash: __hash__()
hs.__hash__(' PROBLEM ')= 0xa638a41
hs.__hash__(' PROBLEN ')= 0xa638a42
hs.__hash__(' PROBLEO ')= 0xa638a43
hs.__hash__(' PROBLEP ')= 0xa638a5c
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find source or algorithm of Python's hash() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070276/where-can-i-find-source-or-algorithm-of-pythons-hash-function)

Comment: @bzlm [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2070276/753117) discuss Python 2.x.

Comment: If you are trying to make your object hashable, the easiest way is to pass the objects data in a tuple to hash() and use that.

Comment: @Winston Ewert somehow I fill that you are absolutely right. Even further: why don't I enclose all data in tuple inside the object? Am I missing something? Sounds too easy..

Comment: @Nikton, if you put all your data inside the tuple, your code will have stuff like self.data[2] instead of self.value which will make it harder to read. Hence why I'd only put the data inside a tuple when its directly helpful.

Comment: @WinstonEwert (I'm probably corpse-digging here but) what about named tuples and `__slots__`?

Comment: @IvanAnishchuk, what about them? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: 1) Instead of putting all the data in a tuple, you can create your whole class as a `NamedTuple`. It almost doesn't have any overhead over a normal tuple, hashes as a tuple, but elements can be accessed by name as attributes. 2) Define a class with `__slots__` defined -- you'll have lightweight objects with a fixed number of fields, but with otherwise normal object operations, and a tuple of all the values can be accessed as `obj.fields` (while no `obj[1]` is possible).

Comment: @IvanAnishchuk, interesting I hadn't thought of 1. 2: yes, although you don't get the hash implementation then.

Comment: Well, you won't get it with a custom class without slots either, you have to implement it either way. But it'll be as easy as `return self.fields.__hash__()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer why they are different is written there:

> Hash values are now values of a new
>   type, Py_hash_t, which is defined to
>   be the same size as a pointer.
>   Previously they were of type long,
>   which on some 64-bit operating systems
>   is still only 32 bits long.

The hashing also consider new values to be calculate, take a look at

```
 sys.hash_info
```

For strings,  you can take a look at http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c?view=markup line 1263   string_hash(PyStringObject *a)

Comment: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c?view=markup , line 1263 string_hash(PyStringObject *a)

Comment: Note that the SVN repository is getting progressively further out of date, as CPython development has migrated to Mercurial: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/unicodeobject.c

Note also that there is no 8-bit string type in Python 3 - only Unicode strings.

Answer (score 3):

I looked up the new function in the source (in unicodeobject.c) and rebuilt it in Python. Here it is:

```
def my_hash(string):
    x = ord(string[0]) << 7
    for c in string:
        x = (1000003 * x) ^ ord(c)
    x ^= len(string)
    needCorrection =  x & (1 << 65)
    x %= 2 ** 64
    if needCorrection:
        x = -~(-x ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    if x == -1:
        x = -2
    return x
```

This is 64-bit only, though. Now with correction for Python's weird behavior when numbers become negative. (You better don't think about this too much.)

Comment: Thanks! I think I can convert it into 32-bit

Comment: I'm not even sure whether it's even possible to implement the algorithm in pure Python. The problem is the same that makes `while n: n >>= 1` an endless loop for negative numbers: Python pretends that negative numbers are infinitely long, with 1s filling up the front.

Comment: You right, something wrong, for ""asdfasdf" I got 2465956724 for my_hash and -1829010572 for hash(). I am removing Edit1