# Python hash() function on strings

Tags: python, hash

How does a hash value of some particular string is calculated in CPython2.7?

For instance, this code:

```
print hash('abcde' * 1000)
```

returns the same value even after I restart the Python process and try again (I did it many times).

So, it seems that `id()` (memory address) of the string doesn't used in this computation, right? Then how?

Comment: "returns the same value even after I restart the Python process and try again" - not guaranteed, and usually not true on Python 3. "it seems that id() (memory address) of the string doesn't used in this computation" - well, of course not. Otherwise, we wouldn't have the invariant that `a == b` implies `hash(a) == hash(b)`.

Comment: I think you need to run `help(hash)` and `help(id)` to understand the difference between the two because they are not the same...

Comment: Maybe this thread will shed some light? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008026/how-hash-is-implemented-in-python-3-2

Comment: @BorrajaX, thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19580412/1959808

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hash values are not dependent on the memory location but the contents of the object itself. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash):

> Return the hash value of the object (if it has one). Hash values are integers. They are used to quickly compare dictionary keys during a dictionary lookup. Numeric values that compare equal have the same hash value (even if they are of different types, as is the case for 1 and 1.0).

See CPython's implementation of `str.__hash__` in:

- [`Objects/unicodeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f205920127bd93eebed044cb1b61834764478ba/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11795-L11814) (for `unicode_hash`)
- [`Python/pyhash.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Python/pyhash.c#L157-L203) (for `_Py_HashBytes`)

Comment: thanks. so it seems, that the hash(string) will be the same from run to run, right?

Comment: @d-d No, it is not guaranteed to be the same every time, but it is guaranteed to return the same value within the same process. If you want a non-changing hash, use [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) functions instead.

Comment: yeah, I thought about it, but I need something faster than any hash function in this module. may be murmur hash or so..

Comment: Check out various hash functions [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed)

Comment: @Lampe2020 See my comment above. It won't even return the same value when you launch a new Python process.