# How are hash values calculated? Why does the hash value for an object change each time the script is run?

Tags: python, hash

I just learned about the `hash` method in Python, and I'm wondering: what is the relationship between an object and its hash value? For example:

```
>>>hash('a') 
1567799509
```

What operations did python perform on the string `'a'` to arrive at `1567799509`? I know it's something related to hexadecimals, but what exactly is the formula used to get a hash value?

Also, I ran the following code:

```
a='a'
b="b"
c='c'
print (hash(a))
print(hash (b))
print(hash(c))
```

And I got this the first time I ran the code:

```
226468662

-199440459

-37886412
```

I got this the second time:

```
-121857168

-774818061

-915254158
```

I got this the third time:

```
1567799509

1439930198

1846375895
```

My questions is this: do hash values change? If so, why?

Comment: I believe it hashes the id of the object by default except for certain types.

Comment: Since you are asking about the ``hash`` function, are you generally aware what a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is?

Comment: They change to avoid denial of service attacks by forcing a (mainly web) application to store many data with the same hash and searching it later (which would be an inefficient linear search).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298023/python-hash-function-on-strings

Answer (score 1):

hash function is used to just compare if two objects in the session are the same.

```
Return the hash value for the given object.
    
    Two objects that compare equal must also have the same hash value, but the
    reverse is not necessarily true.
```

It will only return same value in the same python running session.

To get same hash across multiple runs you need to use cryptographic hash from hashlib library provided in this link:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html?highlight=hashlib