# I want hashlib implementation of built in hash 2.7 algorithm to be used in python 3

Tags: python, hash

I used hash function to generate some partition key value in Python 2. I depended on the built in hash function. I did not know that the implementation is not guaranteed to be the same across versions and I should have used Python hashlib library with specified algorithm like md5 or sha256.

In order to progress in moving to python 3, I need the algorithm to continue to work, I wonder whether there is either python code equivalent of the hash function or utilizing hashlib library to generate the result.

Simple use of hashlib algorithms does not seem to use the same answer
python 3 use different algorithm sipHash and random seed for string hashing.

--update
I tried to run this code in python 2 but it did not work as it generate different result.

```py
def c_mul(a, b):
    return eval(hex((long(a) * b) & 0xFFFFFFFFL)[:-1])
def hash2(self):
    if not self:
        return 0 # empty
    value = ord(self[0]) << 7
    for char in self:
        value = c_mul(1000003, value) ^ ord(char)
    value = value ^ len(self)
    if value == -1:
        value = -2
    return value
```

I need the code to run in python 3 though

--update
modification of the above algorithm by considering 64bit and python3 specific implementation worked. The solution is in the answer.

Comment: The built-in `hash` function isn't meant for the same use cases as those found in `hashlib`; take this opportunity to correct your error.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Here’s hash() implementation from py2.7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008026/how-hash-is-implemented-in-python-3-2 . But you should switch to hashlib. Btw, not only it’s not guaranteed to produce the same result across versions, but also across runs!

Comment: @chepner the data seems to be consistent across runs and we run it in the same machine, using hashlib in historical data is not cost effective for me.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis the question here I want python code that runs in python 3, and produce same output as default built in hash function

Comment: @randomir can't see the 2.7 python implementation of hash algorithm, the one provided in one of the answers is probably for python 3

Comment: Well then it depends on what you're hashing with it, as [it's implemented differently for different types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224935/6144626).

Comment: @Salam, the python 2.7 implementation is provided in the actual question. Read it.

Comment: @randomir I tried running: def c_mul(a, b):
    return eval(hex((long(a) * b) & 0xFFFFFFFFL)[:-1])
def hash2(self):
    if not self:
        return 0 # empty
    value = ord(self[0]) << 7
    for char in self:
        value = c_mul(1000003, value) ^ ord(char)
    value = value ^ len(self)
    if value == -1:
        value = -2
    return value -- it does not provide same results as the hash function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found a solution that looks like working:

```py
%python
import ctypes
def c_mul(a, b):
    return ctypes.c_int64((a * b) & 0xffffffffffffffff).value
def hash2(self):
    if not self:
        return 0 # empty
    value = ord(self[0]) << 7
    for char in self:

        value = c_mul(1000003, value) ^ ord(char)
    value = value ^ len(self)
    if value == -1:
        value = -2
    return value
```

Thank you all for sharing your inputs