# Hash and modulo strings to have equivalent results between C# and Python

Tags: c#, python, hash

I have need to group strings into ten different groups in a deterministic fashion, with some level of uniformity.  The strings are identifiers that come from different sources, all with different (basically unknown) formats.

To accomplish this I decided to hash the strings and mod by 10.  However I am going to be doing this in two different locations and I need their results to be consistent, one is a C# app and the other is a python one.

To ensure consistent hashing I have decided to go with MD5 (reasonably fast and consistent).  Python already has this in the [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html) library and C# has one as in [Cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However I need to int and modulo these numbers with consistency.  In python this is easy

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update(my_string)
int(md5.hexdigest(), 16) % 10
```

But I can't just do this in C# as I only have 64 bit integers.  So my thought is to just grab the last 16 characters from the hex.  In python

```
int(md5.hexdigest()[-16:]) % 10
```

Then in C#

```
// hashString filled via MD5 code in the C# link above
string subHash = hashString.Substring(hashString.Length - 16);
Convert.ToUInt64(subHash, 16) % 10;
```

Now my questions are these.  Are these two methods guaranteed to be equivalent?  Is MD5 a good choice here?  It's certainly consistent but if there is something faster that would be ideal.  Is grabbing the last 16 characters the best way to prevent overflow?

Comment: @zaph the hash doesn't need to be password safe.  SHA256 is better practice for that but these purposes I just need something fast and consistent.  I'm also not applying the mod 10 to a string.  I'm converting to an int first.  The idea being I want to bucket strings of unknown format into ten buckets.  So hash() -> int -> mod10 will do that for me

Comment: I timed MD5 vs SHA256 on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 based laptop for 1,000 iterations. The times were: MD5Hash: 622 nano-seconds/hash, SHA256Hash: 703 nano-seconds/hash. So MD5 was 13% faster and both times were generally insignificant. I have also found SHA256 to be 4 times faster on an iPhone6 than on the Intel laptop. The point is there really needs to be a compelling reason to use outdated methods. A second point is not to engage in premature optimization.

Comment: @zaph the methods are outdated for reasons of security...which is not an issue here

Comment: Your point is made.  Right now MD5 is available on all platforms.  MD2 and MD4 could be viable options if they are faster.  I will profile several methods on the platform and make a performance call.  The crux of the question is would my methodology provide the desired result.  Which hashing function not the major issue here

Comment: It's only unavailable when using FIPS compliant hashing algorithms...we've already established that this is NOT the case here...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question [Where can I find source or algorithm of Python's hash() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070276/where-can-i-find-source-or-algorithm-of-pythons-hash-function) includes the source code for the Python hash function (in C).  Couldn't you implement that in C#.  I'm guessing it would be much faster than MD5.

Python hash function for strings:

```
static long string_hash(PyStringObject *a)
{
    register Py_ssize_t len;
    register unsigned char *p;
    register long x;

    if (a->ob_shash != -1)
        return a->ob_shash;
    len = Py_SIZE(a);
    p = (unsigned char *) a->ob_sval;
    x = *p << 7;
    while (--len >= 0)
        x = (1000003*x) ^ *p++;
    x ^= Py_SIZE(a);
    if (x == -1)
        x = -2;
    a->ob_shash = x;
    return x;
}
```