# String comparison in constant time

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-comparison

I was thinking about faster way to compare two strings.
Checking if value exists in Python set (hash table) has constant time.
Does it means that looking for a string in a **set** has also constant time?

```
print('tya' == 'tya') #O(n)
mySet = set()
mySet.add('tya')
if 'tya' in mySet: #O(1) <-- ???
    print('True')
```

In more general case, does it mean that I can find sub-string in string in linear time???

```
def NaiveFind(largeString, subString):
    mySet = set()
    mySet.add(subString)
    index = -1
    start = 0
    end = len(subString)

    while(end < len(largeString)): #O(n-m)
        windowFromLarge = largeString[start:end]
        if(windowFromLarge in mySet): #O(1) <------- LINEAR ???
        #if(windowFromLarge == subString): #O(m)
            return start
        start += 1
        end += 1

    return index
```

Comment: that wouldnt be faster than just comparing two strings since you'd have to create the set etc

Comment: It's about O(1) relatively to the size of the set. The hashing time for a string seems to be O(len(string)), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070276/where-can-i-find-source-or-algorithm-of-pythons-hash-function

Comment: Of course, but I'm creating set in parallel to actual sub string matching algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say

> Checking if value exists in Python set (hash table) has constant time.

but that's a common oversimplification, made because people don't realize they're doing it or because saying the actual behavior every time would take longer.

Checking if a value exists in a Python set requires an *average-case constant* number of *hashing operations and equality comparisons*, assuming hash collisions don't get out of hand. It does not automatically make hashing operations and equality comparisons constant time.

Your `NaiveFind` algorithm is not linear time, because you've neglected the cost of hash computation (and also because string slicing requires a copy in CPython). The [Rabin-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) uses a refined version of your idea, where the hash is a [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) to avoid this problem. The Rabin-Karp algorithm is average-case linear time, as long as hash collisions don't get out of hand. There are also algorithms like [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) that are guaranteed linear time, and algorithms like [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) that can do *better* than linear time in the usual case.

Comment: I understand it, but if I use it in sub string matching like in algorithm above, does it improve naive method complexity?

Comment: @KocT9H: Nope. See expanded answer.